# YUI 2.9.0 Rich Text Editor in Chrome Populates, then removes editorHTML

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, yui, rich-text-editor

I'm populating the YUI RTE via data from a data row when the row is double clicked or an 'Edit' button is clicked and a row is selected. **IE and FF perform as expected**, but Chrome populates the html content (I know this from debugging in chrome's inspect el feature), and then milliseconds later, it erases it. Any suggestions??

Here's how I'm building the YUI RTE

```
function CreateRTE() {

    //create the RTE:
    emailEditor = new YAHOO.widget.Editor('txtEmlBody', { width: '468px', height: '200px' });

    //After the Editor renders it, we will hide it so the iframe doesn't bleed through
    emailEditor.on('afterRender', emailEditor.hide);

    //Add the insert token button when the toolbar is loaded
    emailEditor.on('toolbarLoaded', function () {

        //Create the button configuration
        var config = { type: 'menu', label: 'Insert Token', value: 'inserttoken', menu: tokenMenu };

        //Add the button to the toolbar
        emailEditor.toolbar.addButtonToGroup(config, 'insertitem');

        //Add the event handler for a menu item click
        emailEditor.toolbar.on('inserttokenClick', function (ev) { this.execCommand('inserthtml', ev.button.value); }, emailEditor, true);

    });

    //render the editor explicitly into a container within the Dialog's DOM:
    emailEditor.render();


}
```

and here's how I'm populating the RTE when a row is double clicked or the edit button is clicked when a row is selected.

```
function EditEmail() {

    //Get the record from the datatable
    var dt = grids.tblEmails.dataTable;
    var tr = dt.getSelectedRows()[0];
    var row = dt.getRecord(tr);

    //Populate the form
    YAHOO.util.Dom.get('hidEmlId').value = row.getData('ID');
    YAHOO.util.Dom.get('hidEmlType').value = row.getData('Type');
    YAHOO.util.Dom.get('txtEmlSubject').value = row.getData('Title');

    emailEditor.setEditorHTML(row.getData('Body'));

    //Show the dialog
    dialogs.dlgEmail.show();

}
```

I did read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016105/yahoo-yui-2-rich-text-editor-cant-get-seteditorhtml-method-to-work-whats) article, but the issue doesn't seem to match. The context of the html editor is being populated, and then removed.... sooo , any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try updating the editor's backing text area with the html `( row.getData('Body') ),` prior to setting the editor's html `(emailEditor.setEditorHTML(row.getData('Body'));)` . This should allow it to work in Chrome/Safari.